# How to automatically populate range of cells from other sheet using a drop-down menu

Tags: excel

I'm unable to automatically populate range of cells based on the month chosen from the drop-down menu.

I have 2 sheets (dashboard and data dump). In the dashboard tab I have a drop-down menu with a list of months (from June to March 2020). Below that I have 5 columns, list of material, start date, end date, cost, and received/not received (Y/N). The data dump also contains the same columns/info as the dashboard tab.

The objective was to choose a specific month from the drop-down menu, which then in a data dump tab, finds all of the materials that are anticipated to be received in the same month and automatically populate the list. The end date would be the 'anticipated to be received' date and all corresponding material would be automatically populated in the dashboard tab.

[image: Dashboard tab]

I've tried to use INDEX(MATCH) formulas in Excel but I realized 2 problems:

1. The drop-down menu months' dates are always the 1st day of the month whereas, End Date column in data dump tab has different dates. I found a workaround with this by subtracting End Dates to always equal the 1st day of the month
2. Because there are no unique formulas or IDs, the Excel stops at the first material it finds using INDEX(MATCH) which meant if I copied this formula to a range of cells underneath the first row, the results were always the same material.

I've watched some Youtube instructors use UNIQUE/FILTER functions but apparently these functions are not available to the public yet. I have entered the info manually for now but what I would like to do is to choose the month in the drop-down menu and have the equipment list below automatically populate.

Comment: You could do this with a `Pivot table` and a `Slicer`. Seems the ideal option for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Filter, advanced filter would also work.

Comment: @Zac that's a good idea - however, the cost column also contains comments (e.g., included in motherboard) and pivot table is unable to pick that up as it's in the value field. Also, if i put "end date" as filter field, then i cannot add end date again to the column field. I'm also not sure how to put the end date as a column as well as rows (otherwise, if it's just in column field then it expands the table too much).

Comment: @HarassedDad doesn't the filter only work when I filter in data dump tab? Not sure how i would filter a blank table in the dashboard tab. Perhaps the description above was confusing but the table above would be blank with only a drop-down menu, and once the month is selected, it automatically fetches the list of material that was anticipated in that month and automatically populates the table with all relevant information (start/end date, cost, and received columns).

Comment: advanced filter will copy data from a database (range of cells) to a blank destination. You would need to write code to automate the process.